# phantomjs - Clear local storage from command line?

Tags: ruby, cookies, phantomjs, local-storage

I'm using phantomjs headless driver and having it crawl a couple pages on the web, including sign in with credentials. I'm using it in combo with [Watir](https://watir.com/) (`ruby` library for automated web browsing).

The problem is that I need it to start fresh each time with empty cookies and local storage. I was able to set custom path for cookies (`--cookies-file`), and then clean that file, but can't do the same for local storage (`--local-storage-path` doesn't seem to do anything). My phantom version is `2.1.1` (There is [a reported issue with local storage](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11596) in versions prior to 2.0.0)

Any clues are appreciated. At least it would be great to know where local storage is stored by default (that would fix my immediate need).

Comment: Since you can execute arbitrary Javascript, wouldn't running something like this suffice? `for(var key of Object.keys(localStorage)) { delete localStorage[key] }`

Comment: @maxpleaner Thanks for your comment. I'm running headless. Are you proposing to run js from command line?

Comment: The fact that it's headless shouldn't make any difference. You should still be able to run commands in the Phantom API. `evaluate` is one of those commands which lets you run javascript in the context of the web page. [source](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html). Be forewarned that you will not see `console.log` or errors by default. See [onConsoleMessage](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html) and [onError](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/handler/on-error.html)

Comment: What OS/env are you running phantomjs on? I'm using phantomjs 2.1.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Centos 6.3 and it works fine. If this problem is solved you could just cleanup the folder you specify or simply forward local-storage-path to /dev/null

Comment: @ffeast Thanks for your comment. Mac OS locally and Linux RedHat remotely. `local-storage-path` does not seem to work. In the interim, I found where phantomjs stores local storage by default (`$HOME/.local/share/Ofi\ Labs/PhantomJS/*`). What I'm not clear on, is how to use `phantomjs` JavaScript API from command line.

Comment: You can't run it from command line. As @Max Pleaner suggested you need to run the code cleaning up localstorage from your page's context. But I would figure out what's actually wrong with your phantomjs version - maybe comment on this issue [link](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11596)

Comment: Sorry, @ffeast, not understanding (and appologies for noobiness). I run phantomjs headless, using Watir (or prior was using Selenium), in Ruby. I don't have traditional browser. I don't believe either expose phantomjs object. Basically, my Ruby code never touches js. How can I get access to the phantomjs object in this context?

Comment: If you have for an example, that would help a lot.